# Codenameone ComponentGroup not displayed in Android skins

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, codenameone

Using the latest Codenameone version, I can't get the ComponentGroups to work on Android.

They seem to work fine in the different iOS simulator skins, but not in the Android ones (ex.: Galaxy S7).

Just running the quick example in the code outputs this :
[image]

Running on the actual devices, gives the exact same result as on the emulators

For the records, setting ComponentGroupBool in the theme's constants did not seem to change anything. 
I also tried using the default unaltered themes, with the same results..

Any ideas what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/ComponentGroup.html):

> **Important!!!** A component group does nothing by default unless explicitly activated by the theme by enabling the ComponentGroupBool
>   constant (by default, this can be customized via the groupFlag
>   property). This allows logical grouping without changing the UI for
>   themes that don't need grouping.

So `ComponentGroupBool` in the theme constants should work and give you these UIID's. However, it won't look like the pictures above in Android as there are no styles to match that on Android.

You can also force the component group appearance regardless of OS by using `group.setForceGroup(true)`.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer!  I did not managed to have the setForceGroup to work (all I did was get the group returned by the Component.enclosed method and call setForcedGroup(true) on it, so I'm sure I'm missing something), but knowing that it's normal for it not to work on Android by default because of the styles was helpful to me. I could just add some style for the ComponentGroup to my theme and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: How do you define "not work"? Was the UIID set? Notice that there would be no styling on Android for these UIID's. You can use the Component Inspector tools to look at the UIID's of the components in the hierarchy.

Comment: Sorry about that, I misunderstood your original comment thinking that by using the forcegroup it would force the "appearance" (making it look the same as what it was for me on iOS) regardless of OS.  The UIID's were appropriately set.  I just need to "play" with themes and styles now.  Thanks for the help! (I've upvoted your answer, but since I'm fairly new around here, my vote does'nt really count.. ;) )